# Django forms creates table rows by itself

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using django with forms. And on every one of them django add `<tr>` & `<td>` before the different inputs.

Example:

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):

username = forms.CharField(label='username', max_length=50)
password = forms.CharField(label='password', widget=forms.PasswordInput, max_length=100)
```

views.py:

```
class Login(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

In the html file i simply import the form via

```
{{ form | linebreaks }}
```

But now the given html code looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="*csrftoken*">
    <p><tr><th><label for="id_username">username:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="50" required id="id_username"></td></tr><br><tr><th><label for="id_password">password:</label></th><td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="100" required id="id_password"></td></tr></p>
    <br>
    <button class="button" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

But why does django do this? Can't it simply just use the input tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
{{form.as_p|linebreaks}}
```

instead of :

```
{{form|linebreaks}}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Any idea why django does it this way?

Comment: your welcome. i think it's the default that show inputs like tables. exactly like admin page in django